# C++ grpc/grpc.h not Found

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

i got the following Problem: I'm currently build a Application that uses gRPC for Inter-Service-Communication. I wrote my `.proto` Files and generate the Code using `protoc`.
After i started the writing implementation i got the error `fatal error: 'grpc/grpc.h' file not found`.

My Project uses CMake as it's Build System.

Main CMake File:

```
# Project Name
project("myproject")

# Options
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17)
set (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../../../build/archive)
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../../../build/lib)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../../../build/runtime)

set (CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set (CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK 0)

# CMake Required Version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

# Include Directories
include_directories("include")

# Doxygen
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    # set input and output files
    set(DOXYGEN_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/docs/Doxyfile.in)
    set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)

    # request to configure the file
    configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)
    message("Doxygen build started")

    # note the option ALL which allows to build the docs together with the application
    add_custom_target( docs ALL
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message("Doxygen need to be installed to generate the doxygen documentation")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)


# Google Test
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# Directories
add_subdirectory(src/Core)
add_subdirectory(src/CoreGUI)
add_subdirectory(src/gRPCServer)
add_subdirectory(src/CameraServer)
add_subdirectory(src/TestRunner)
add_subdirectory(libraries/Math)
add_subdirectory(libraries/ImageProcessing)
add_subdirectory(libraries/DataStructures)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` of the sub-Project that generates the Error:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cc)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
find_package(protobuf REQUIRED)

add_executable(myproject.Core ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myproject.Core grpc)
target_link_libraries(myproject.Core protobuf)
```

I didn't get any CMake Errors that it couldn't find gRPC or anything like that.
The Error only appears when i run: `cmake --build build-files/ --target myproject.CameraServer`

I installed GRPC/protobuf using homebrew on mac (macos ventura)

This is the only file in my project that currently does anything with grpc,
and that one does throw the error:

```cpp
#include <grpc/grpc.h>
#include <grpcpp/security/server_credentials.h>
#include <grpcpp/server.h>
#include <grpcpp/server_builder.h>
#include <grpcpp/server_context.h>

#include "_grpc/Configuration.grpc.pb.h"
#include "../../libraries/DataStructures/RPCServerConfig.h"

namespace myproject::Core::Services {
    class ConfigurationServiceProvider final : public ConfigurationService::Service {
    public:
        grpc::Status GetHUDConfig(grpc::ServerContext *context, const ConfigRequest* request, HUDConfig* response);

        void StartServer();
    };
}
```

i followed this tutorial for grpc: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/

Can someone help?

Comment: Have a look at this couple of places: [1](https://github.com/faaxm/exmpl-cmake-grpc/blob/master/proto/CMakeLists.txt), and [2](https://www.f-ax.de/dev/2020/11/08/grpc-plugin-cmake-support.html). You may be missing something in your CMakeLists.txt file to get gRPC working yet.

Comment: No kind of expert on CMake but I don't see anything in your subproject configuration that specifies where to find the include files that your build doesn't find

Comment: Is the subproject CMakeLists you posted the CameraServer? If yes, it sounds like the package was found, but the necessary headers are not present. Have you tried linking publicly to `${GRPC_LIBRARIES}`?

Comment: Try `find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)` `target_link_libraries(myproject.Core gRPC::grpc++)` which I found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/cpp/README.md)